# ASP MVC Binding IList in partial view issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm attempting to submit prospective customer information to the server using a HTML form. Firstly, I have a main view that holds an ajax form which determines how many customers we want to submit. After submitting this, it populates the partial view with the required amount of inputs. Example HTML extract for the title of two customers:

```
<td class="quoteStandardCell"><input name="sessionPriv.indi[0].title" tabindex="1" class="visualfilesinputtext" id="sessionPriv_indi_0__title" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" value=""></td>

<td class="quoteStandardCell"><input name="sessionPriv.indi[1].title" tabindex="11" class="visualfilesinputtext" id="sessionPriv_indi_1__title" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" value=""></td>
```

Everything looks to generate correctly, however upon submitting the customer information, it fails to submit the first customer's information (indi[0]). When I put a break point in my controller, sessionPriv.indi only has 1 individual, that individual being the second set of customer details.

So basically, it's not submitting the first set of customer data and I have no idea why. Any guidance would be much appreciated (still fairly new to ASP). I have included code exstracts below.

**Main View (CreatePrivate.aspx)**

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("indiView", "Visualfiles", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "indiPartial", HttpMethod = "post", OnSuccess = "pageLoaded()" }, new { id = "genIndiForm" }))
        { %>
            <table class="visualfilestable" id="indiHeadTable">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="quoteIndiHeader">Prospect Details</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="quoteIndi quoteHeader">
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Prospect Type</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.DropDownListFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.type, new SelectList(privateType.types, "typeID", "typeName"), new { @class = "visualfilesinputdropdown", @onchange = "showIndiCount(this.value)", @id = "privateType" }) %></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell IndiCountTR">Number of Individuals</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell IndiCountTR"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indiCount, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", type = "number", min = "2", max = "10", id = "indiCount" })%></td>

                    <td><input class="visualfilespostbutton" type="submit" id="Submitbutton" value="Continue" onclick="document.getElementById('visualfilesbusy').style.display = 'inline';" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <%} %>

        <%using (Html.BeginForm("createPrivate", "Visualfiles", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createPrivForm", name = "privForm" }))
        { %>
            <div class="indiPartial" id="indiPartial"></div>

        <% } %>
```

**Partial View (_indiData.ascx)**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ASPOnline.Models.VisualfilesSession>" %>

<div class="indiWrapper">
<%if (Model != null)
{ %>

    <% for (var i = 0; i < Model.sessionPriv.indiCount; i++)
    { %>
        <div class="indiDiv">
            <table class="indiTable">
                <tr class="quoteIndiHeader">
                    <td colspan="8">Individual <%= i+1 %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="quoteIndi">
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Title</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].title, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 1.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">House Name / Flat</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].houseName, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 4.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Locality</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].locality, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 7.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Postcode</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].postcode, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 10.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>
                </tr>


                <tr class="quoteIndi">
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Given Name</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].givenName, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 2.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">House Number</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].houseNumber, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 5.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Town</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].town, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 8.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Daytime Contact</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].daytimeContact, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 10.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>
                </tr>


                <tr class="quoteIndi">
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Family Name</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].familyName, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 3.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Street Name</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].street, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 6.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">County</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].county, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 9.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>

                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Mobile Number</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].mobile, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 10.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="quoteIndi">
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell">Email</td>
                    <td class="quoteStandardCell"><%: Html.TextBoxFor(n => Model.sessionPriv.indi[i].email, new { @class = "visualfilesinputtext", @autofocus = "autofocus", tabindex=(i.ToString() + 10.ToString()).AsInt() })%></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% } %>
    <div class="indiPartialSubmit"><input class="visualfilespostbutton" type="submit" value="Create Private" /></div>
 <% } %>
</div>
```

**Model Data**

```
    public class individual
{
    // Name
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string givenName { get; set; }
    public string familyName { get; set; }

    // Address Details
    public string houseName { get; set; }
    public string houseNumber { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public string town { get; set; }
    public string county { get; set; }
    public string postcode { get; set; }

    // Contact Details
    public string daytimeContact { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public individual() {
        title = "";
        givenName = "";
        familyName = "";
        houseName = "";
        street = "";
        locality = "";
        town = "";
        county = "";
        postcode = "";
        daytimeContact = "";
        mobile = "";
        email = "";
    }
}

public class priv
{
    public int type { get; set; }   // Individual/Couple/Group
    public int indiCount { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public IList<individual> indi { get; set; }

    public priv()
    {
        type = 0;
        indiCount = 0;
        role = "";
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createPrivate(VisualfilesSession viewSession)
    {
        return PartialView(getNextPage(viewSession, "createPrivate"), savedSession);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a comment but i cant yet.

Have you looked at web developer console in browser? is this array properly passed to request ?

what is `VisualfilesSession` ?

Comment: Looks like I need to work on my debugging skills lol. I used the developer console and it is being passed. I moved my breakpoint to the point where it has not been directly manipulated in my code and it is there. Seems I'm losing it later down the line (my controller makes a call to a broker which is (I'm guessing) causing the issue).